# Function in Haskell for returning other element of a pair

Tags: haskell, tuples

Is there a function in Haskell which will return the other member of a pair say for example calling the function "other": other 'D' ('D','W') would return 'W' and other 'W' ('D','W') returns 'D'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
other :: Eq a => a -> (a, a) -> a
other x (y,z) | x == y = z | x == z = y | otherwise = error "undefined"
```

You could do something like this. Note, what happens if the character exists outside the tuples range of values?

```
test1 = other 'D' ('D','W') -- * W
test2 = other 'W' ('D','W') -- * D
test3 = other 'X' ('D','W') -- * error...
```

Per @RottenBrain's suggestion. The `Maybe`monad could be used to handle failure cases.

```
other :: Eq a => a -> (a, a) -> Maybe a 
other x (y,z) | x == y = Just z | x == z = Just y | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: I think he knows how to write the function and would just like to know if it's already part of Haskell's library. Also, `undefined` would be better than `error`, in this case.

Comment: @Paul Manta 
`undefined` is defined in terms of `error`...
`undefined = error "Prelude; undefined"`

Comment: I will suggest using Maybe a rather then errors: ```other :: Eq a => a -> (a, a) -> Maybe a
other x (y,z)
  | x == y = Just z
  | x == z = Just y
  | otherwise = Nothing```

Answer (score 7):

"Is there a function in Haskell that...."?

You can get a pretty good idea to the answer to any of this type of question by using Hoogle.  The beauty of Haskell is that the type often really contrains what your proposed function can be, and Hoogle is the tool that lets you get a pretty comprehensive answer.

In this case, we are given a tuple, and want to get one of the values in the tuple as a result.

```
(a, b)->a->b  or (a, b)->b->a
```

But wait!  Haskell can't output two different types from the same function, so an implicit constraint has been given- `a` must be the same as `b`.  The type is now:

```
(a, a)->a->a
```

(this narrows the function search space even more, making Hoogle even more useful).

Again, wait....  We forgot something.  The type `a` needs to have an `(==)` operator in order to do the test....  Great, even a further narrowing:

```
Eq a=>(a, a)->a->a
```

Now we can type this into Hoogle, and see....  pretty much nothing useful.

Is this a failure?  Not at all!  Hoogle is pretty comprehensive, and in my previous experiences if it ain't there, it probably ain't a standard function, so write it yourself.

(It isn't surprising to me that this function isn't standard....  Tuples are rarely used to pass around generic lists of items of the same type, that is more of a list-y thing)